# Updating a cell value breaks row style. NPOI, C#

Tags: c#, npoi

Good evening, recently i was trying to update cell's value in .xls file, using NPOI library(C#), but, when i do that with `cell.SetCellValue("anyvalue");`,

I am able to see the changes only in some cells. Other cell are just empty.

Tried to save cell's style and re-write it using `cell.CellStyle`, but still the same.

Generally speaking, i get only half of the values that have to be filled in places.

Using that code, where nameAndValues[0] contains cell name, and nameAndValues[1] contains its value.

```
using (FileStream rstr = new FileStream(currentPath + $"/{excelName}", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(rstr);
                    var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
                    using (FileStream wstr = new FileStream(currentPath + $"/{excelName}", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var cr = new CellReference(namesAndValue[i, 0]);
                            var row = sheet.CreateRow(cr.Row);
                            var cell = row.CreateCell(cr.Col);
                            cell.SetCellValue(namesAndValue[i, 1]);

                        }
                        workbook.Write(wstr);
                        wstr.Close();
                    }
                    rstr.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Tried to change FileMode and FileAccess, but nothing worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `sheet.CreateRow(0)`, the first row of the sheet will be wiped out and an empty row will be inserted with no style. The same goes with `row.CreateCell()`.

So you are calling `CreateRow` over and over again, making only the last value of the row survive.

I think this might be the problem.